# PlaySound() winmm does not play existing sound

Tags: c++, opengl, winmm

I just have a bit project of asteroid game in c++, opengl, and glut. I am trying to play sound of thrust ship using the `Windows.h` and `mmsystem.h` in minGW and Visual Studio Code before I go put my line compiler code.

```
g++ GLasteroid.cpp -o GLasteroid.exe -L"C:/MinGW/freeglut/lib" -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lfreeglut -lwinmm -I"C:\MinGW\freeglut\include\GL"
```

I have a small function `accelerate` execute when  the Glut specialKey UP is pressed:

```
   void accelerate()    //make ship accelerate
            {
            if (Shipacell == true){
                glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
                glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
                glVertex2f(0.0f, -0.075f);
                glVertex2f(0.01f, 0.0f);
                glVertex2f(0.01f, -0.062f);
                glVertex2f(-0.017f, 0.0f);
                glVertex2f(-0.017f, -0.062f);
                glVertex2f(0.024f, 0.0f);
                glVertex2f(0.024f, -0.049f);
                glVertex2f(-0.035f, 0.0f);
                glVertex2f(-0.035f, -0.049f);
                //PlaySound(TEXT("sounds/thrust.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME);//Lag delay bad, with SND_ASYNC not work
                PlaySound(L"\\sounds\\thrust.wav", 0, SND_FILENAME );// got error parameter 1
            }

    }
```

Look in method 1, the song play with delay long lag with `SND_ASYNC` not work.
With method 2, I got an error on the terminal:

```
In file included from c:\mingw\include\windows.h:62,
                 from GLasteroid.cpp:8:
c:\mingw\include\mmsystem.h:1561:24: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'BOOL PlaySoundA(LPCSTR, HMODULE, DWORD)'
 BOOL WINAPI PlaySoundA(LPCSTR,HMODULE,DWORD);
```

If I try to put all the path `C:\\MinGW\\projetos\\sounds\\thrust.wav`, I got same error.

If anyone has any idea, please post.

Comment: `PlaySoundW(...)`

Comment: Is that path really correct? The leading back-slash makes the path relative from the drives root (e.g. `C:\sounds\thrust.wav`).

Comment: yes correct look the first method by TEXT... PlaySound(TEXT("sounds/thrust.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME);//Lag delay bad, with SND_ASYNC not work if i just put method of L..... got error on terminal if i try all path C:\\MinGW\\projetos\\sounds\\thrust.wav got same error